# Bootstrap: Remove border and arrows for dropdown field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I remove the dropdown-arrows without messing up the height and at the same time hide the border when I use Bootstrap 3?

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qKC7yK?p=preview) where I try to do this. The hide arrow (class custom-select) is based on [this blog](http://www.currelis.com/hiding-select-arrow-firefox-30.html) copying [this code](http://jsbin.com/pozomu/4/edit).

Perhaps better check out the plunk, but here is the CSS:

```
.no-border {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.custom-select {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0 2em;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.custom-select:hover {
    border-color: #999;
}

.custom-select:before {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: 0 0.625em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1em;
    z-index: -1;
}

.custom-select select {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

.custom-select select::-ms-expand {
    display: none; /* to ie 10 */
}

.custom-select select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* little trick for custom select elements in mozilla firefox  17/06/2014 @rodrigoludgero */

/* pseudo class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any */

:-moz-any(.custom-select):before {
    background-color: #fff; /* this is necessary for overcome the caret default browser */
    pointer-events: none; /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events  */
    z-index: 1; /* this is necessary for overcome the pseudo element */
}
```

**Edit:** If I add !important to my no-border border, then it solves the border-related problem:

```
.no-border {
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

So then remains the height-change issue when toggeling custom-select for removing/adding the dropdown-arrows...

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/dfdon4gb/

Comment: I added the `.custom-select:before{display:none !important;}` in your css to remove the dropdown arrow as per your first requirement _"How can I remove the dropdown-arrows without messing up the height?"_  See Here - http://jsfiddle.net/xj3zjLmz/

Comment: Oh, see now. But what does it solve (compared to the plunk I already have, link in question)? The removing of the arrows works (as in your fiddle). My problem is the added height (if you add some content below in your fiddle and remove/add the custom-select-class, or just check out my plunk, you will see this) and the removing of the border at the same time.

Comment: If I instead use the '!Important' in my no-border border definition, then it solves the border problem. Then the added height-problem remains...

Comment: @MaryMelody Your fiddle uses font-awesome in it. The OP is not. If this was the case, you can very easily remove the arrow by removing the `fa-caret-down` class from the select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `!important` should really be used only as a last resort.
In my opinion, its the lazy way out.

In your `.custom-select` class, you have two things

```
.custom-select {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0; /* "0 0 2em" reads as margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 2em; (32px) */
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Your margin was `margin: 0 0 2em;`, and you were giving it a border, youself. I just removed that, instead. Or you could just change it to `border: 0;`

Also: Semantics... But:

```
<select id="status" class="form-control" ng-class="{'no-border': border}" id="inputEmail3">
    <option>First option</option>
    <option>Another option</option>
    <option>We also have a tird</option>
</select>
```

You have two id attributes. You should remove one.

Comment: +0001 for _using `!important` is the lazy way out._

Comment: I wont lie... Ive def used it way more than I should have, in the past. ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Oberst! And I realize that I do not need the no-border class for the dropdown-field at all for what I need (I just toggle the custom-select-class), and therefore no reason to use !important :) Thanks!